# Viewport or Screen resolution for fullscreen images

Tags: html, css, web, browser, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive website. On my website there is a gallery of images. If I click on one image, the image will be displayed in fullscreen. So my question is:

The website will be displayed in viewport resolution although the screen has a much greater resolution. Will images in fullscreen mode displayed in viewport resolution or in screen resolution?